# Azure table storage select column query in lookup activity

Tags: azure, odata, azure-data-factory, lookup, azure-table-storage

I have azure table storage with table with multiple columns which is my source data for the Lookup activity.
I want to retrieve/select specific columns using OData query in the Lookup activity. Is there any way to select specific columns in OData.
I tried select='Column_name' which do not works.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Reading up the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-table-storage#copy-activity-properties, I don't believe query projection (i.e. using $select) is supported.

Answer (score 0):

No, OData query can only filter the value of column. You can get the whole table's value and then use this expression to get specific column's value: `@activity('Get File Data').output.firstRow.columnName`.